# Python Variable not defined when it is?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
import linecache
print("Welcome to the online safety quiz!") 



registereduser = input("Are you a registered user? Enter Y or N: ") 

registereduser = registereduser.upper() 


if registereduser == "Y":
    username = input("What is your school username? ")
    stored_username = linecache.getline("{0}.csv".format(username), 4)
    print (stored_username)

    if username == stored_username:
        stored_password = linecache.getline("{0}.csv".format(username), 5)
        stored_fullname = linecache.getline("{0}.csv".format(username), 1)
        print("Hello {0} ").format(stored_fullname)
        password = input("What is your password? ")
        import hashlib, uuid
        salt = "87e6781077c7420cbc160853b62693f3"
        hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(password.encode('utf-8') + salt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    if stored_password == hashed_password:

        print("You have logged in successfully")
    else:
        print("ERROR Your details do not match the one in our database please retry or register again ")
```

This is the error i get when i run the code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joel\python", line 25, in 
    if stored_password == hashed_password:
NameError: name 'stored_password' is not defined

Please bear in mind i already have data files stored in the same folder which the program retrieves data from...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `stored_password` is only declared if `username == stored_username`. Fix this by declaring it beforehand with a default value.

```
stored_password = ''
if username == stored_username:
    ...
```

Comment: Using a string might not be best as conceivably a user could enter it as their username...

Answer (score 0):

Stored_password is defined locally within the if statement. you need to add stored_password = None on line 16

Comment: If statements do not have their own level of scope.

Comment: I misspoke, What I mean is, if the username entered does not match the username_stored stored_password will not be defined, becasue Stored_password is only defined in the conditional... (forgive me)

Answer (score -1):

Your indentation is off. With the current indention its on the same level as if the username == stored_username.

If you indent your if statement it should work.